# Are there any tools on the market that employ prosodic research to help overcome speech impediments?

Tags: second-lang-acquisition, prosody

I see a lot of language learning software, apps, intelligent games on the market, but nearly all of them focuses on grammar and lexical aspects of linguistics. I wonder if any techniques are dedicated to prosodic aspects of language acquisition, to helping learnings lose their accent or children overcome speech impediments.

Comment: Didactics and methodology of teaching/studying is offtopic here, you may simply not find anyone who would be able to answer. Also, searching for tools usually generate opinionated answers.

Comment: I just wonder how knowledge of prosody is operationalized in technology for e.g. language learning or speech impediment correction

Answer (score 3):

There is some software available. For instance, the [Get Rid of Your Accent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.batcs.accentukonedemo) app and the many [Speech Therapy Apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=speech%20therapy&c=apps).

When it comes to speech therapy dealing with impediments, this is often so highly individualised that it almost always requires a trained person to intervene. That is not to say that some computer-assisted solutions would not be possible or useful but any software solution will only be a small part of the intervention.

Also if you look at the kind of work it takes to achieve prosodic proficiency - particularly when it comes to accent removal, you can see that software can only take you so far. I recommend looking at Melody Noll's Ameritalk for some examples: http://www.ameri-talk.com.